# Wann sollte ich „passieren” und wann „stattfinden” verwenden?

Tags: word-usage, verb-usage

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen „passieren” und „stattfinden” oder sind das Synonyme? „Das wird nicht passieren” und  „Das wird nicht stattfinden” bedeuten doch das gleiche? Falls es keine Synonyme sind, würde es mich interessieren, wann ich welches benutzen sollte.

Vielen Dank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Synonyme sind es nicht, aber die Bedeutungen überschneiden sich, wobei »passieren« breiter aufgestellt ist.

> Eine Veranstaltung findet statt, ein Unfall passiert.

Umgekehrt wirst du das selten hören.

Und in diesen Fällen wäre es unpassend bzw. falsch, »stattfinden« zu verwenden:

> Was passiert mit diesen ausrangierten Elektrogeräten? *(Was soll damit
> geschehen?)*
>
> Der Zug hat die Grenze passiert. *(überschritten)*
>
> Die Zinsen sind im Keller, es muss endlich etwas passieren! *(Handlungsbedarf!)*
>
> Pass auf, dass dir nichts passiert! *(dass dir nichts zustößt)*
>
> Die Tomaten wurden passiert. *(durch ein Sieb gedrückt, dadurch zu Brei verarbeitet)*
>
> Tennis: Er hat seinen am Netz stehenden Gegner passiert. *(hat den Ball an
> ihm vorbei geschlagen)*

»Passieren« im Sinne von »geschehen« wird im Allgemeinen für Vorgänge verwendet, die unterlaufen, von sich aus erfolgen, ungewollt,
während »stattfinden« in der Regel Planung impliziert.

Ein Fall (mit den von dir zitierten Sätzen), bei dem beide Begriffe möglich sind, wäre etwa:

> »Bitte? Sie wollen ab Juni das doppelte Gehalt?«
>
> »Wie ich schon sagte.«
>
> »Das wird nicht stattfinden/passieren, so viel ist sicher.«